# IOS: effect curl as maps in iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, curl, maps

In iPad maps there is curl effects; I have two questions:

1- what's the way to implement the same effect but I want a total curl and not partial

2- the flap at the bottom right, is only a graphic effect? or I can do it with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)? It was added in iOS5 and may lead you in the right direction.

There's also a UIViewAnimationTransition which involves a curl, but it goes from one view to another - not really like the map does it.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations]
```